# how can i optimize a django oracle connection?

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models, model

I work with Oracle Database and lastest Django but when i use the default user model is the query very slow

what can i do?

Comment: First step: profile your code to see where the problem really is - such as with https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar and/or your DB's own logging to see where the issue is. Then come back to us and edit your question to help us help you a bit more

Comment: thx i use the debug toolbar and i found the problems...

Comment: it was a the auth_user table this table had use min 150 sec to load and i have add a index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add an index.